# Pause Interval for Final Result IBM Watson Speech to Text

Tags: speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I was wondering if it is possible to tweak the pause interval the engine uses to determine final results -- in effect trading off more final results with less contextual accuracy or less final results with more contextual accuracy. Thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Why was the above question voted down?  It's a reasonable thing to ask.

The answer is no, it is currently not possible.  The final result now comes after 0.5 of non-speech audio is detected following some speech.

Comment: Thank you Arthur, I greatly appreciate it! I'm not sure why it was voted down, I had assumed I committed some faux pas or wasn't detailed enough.